# Blow-up of $V(x,y)$ and $V((x,y)^2)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Does the blow-up of $V(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ is isomorphic to the blow-up of $V((x,y)^2)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$? Here I mean that the centers are $V(x,y)$ and $V((x,y)^2)$ respectively.

I I consider it in the classical sense $\{(x,y,[x:y])\}$ seems to be isomorphic to $\{(x,y,[x^2:xy:y^2]\}$ via Veronnese embedding but the blowup is the closure of these spaces.

If I consider blowup via the $\text{Proj}$ of the Rees Algebras I should try to prove that $A[xt,yt]\simeq A[x^2t,xyt,y^2t]$ with $A=k[x,y]$ or $k[x,y,u,v]/(yu-xv)\simeq k[x,y,x^2t, xyt,y^2t]$.

Is there some general result wich says that the blows-up of $V(I^k)$ is the same of $V(I)$?

Comment: One cannot compare at the level of Rees rings. Only their proj are isomorhic.

Comment: @Youngsi Thanks for this precision! For getting such an isomorphism could we take $f:A[u,v]/(vx-uy)\to A[x^ 2t,xyt,y^2t]$ with $u\mapsto yx^2t$ and $v\mapsto xy^2t$? How then proving that $\text{Proj}(A[x^2t,xyt,y^2t])\to\text{Proj}(A[u,v]/(vx-uy)$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Hi, one only needs to compare affine covers. The source is covered by $D(xt), D(yt)$, and the target is covered by $D(x^2t), D(y^2t)$. For instance, on $D(xt)$ and $D(x^2)$, their coordinate rings are $k[x,y,y/x]$.

Comment: @Yougsu thanks all seems clear now. I post an answer but feel free to post youself an answer and I valide it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to Yougsu I think I have it: on $D_+(xt)$ we have for the blowing up of $(x,y)$, 
$$ \text{Spec}\,A\left[\frac{xt}{xt},\frac{yt}{xt}\right]\simeq\text{Spec}\,A\left[\frac{y}{x}\right]=\text{Spec}\,k\left[x,y,\frac{y}{x}\right]$$
and in the other hand on $D_+(x^2t)$ we have for the blowup of $(x,y)^2$:
$$ \text{Spec}\,A\left[\frac{x^2t}{x^2t},\frac{xyt}{x^2t},\frac{y^2t}{x^2t}\right]\simeq \text{Spec}\,A\left[\frac{xy}{x^2},\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right]=\text{Spec}\,k\left[x,y,\frac{y}{x},\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right]=\text{Spec}\,k\left[x,y,\frac{y}{x}\right]$$
On $D_+(yt)$ and $D_+(y^2t)$ we have the same thing and I guess these two isomorphisms are guling well so we get our isomorphism between the two blows-up.